# Get port protocol details from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get port protocol details from a URL. Can some one please help me? I have tried with some code -

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");
        string requested = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port;
```

Problem 1 - This code does not tell me whether this is TCP or UDP or ISMP

Problem 2 - This code does not check the actual port/protocol details of the URL.

Problem 3 - I am not able to build the URL if I have URL like this - "stackoverflow.com".

Please some one help me.

Thanks
Gulrej

Comment: "stackoverflow.com" is not a URL, it's a hostname. You have to assume, guess or decide the other information.

Comment: Ok that I understand. But if I have a full URL , can I know whether it is TCP/UDP or ISMP ?

Answer (score 3):

This may help, It worked for me

```
string url = "http://www.contoso.com:8080/letters/readme.html";

 Regex r = new Regex(@"^(?<proto>\w+)://[^/]+?(?<port>:\d+)?/",
                          RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));
      Match m = r.Match(url);
      if (m.Success)
         Console.WriteLine(r.Match(url).Result("${proto}${port}"));
```

Comment: But still I am not able to know the TCP/UDP ?

Comment: How to know the TCP/UDP/ISMP from a URL?

Comment: Full explanation of how this exact code works is on the Microsoft site - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-extract-a-protocol-and-port-number-from-a-url#example

Answer (score 0):

With url = stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

You're easily to know :

Protocol = http or https.

And

Port = default port = 80 (http) or 443 (https)

In case having the specific port,it will be placed after hostname like this 
[stackoverflow.com:8180]

Comment: Can you please post me some sample code? And i want to know the TCP/UDP/ISMP of this request also.

Comment: TCP is a transport layer protocol , and HTTP is an application layer protocol that run over TCP.

Comment: So is it possible to fetch those information using C# asp.net